# Serilog - multiple log files

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I am using Serilog for logging and cant' figure out how to separate log events to different files. For example, I want to log errors to error_log-ddmmyyyy.txt and warnings to warn_log-ddmmyyyy.txt.

Here goes my logger configuration:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Logger(lc =>
                lc.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.WithProperty("Level", "Warning"))
                    .WriteTo.RollingFile(
                        Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Logs\warn_log-{Date}.txt"),
                        outputTemplate: OutputTemplate))
            .WriteTo.Logger(lc =>
                lc.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.WithProperty("Level", "Error"))
                    .WriteTo.RollingFile(
                        Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Logs\error_log-{Date}.txt"),
                        outputTemplate: OutputTemplate))
            .CreateLogger();
```

It only works when I specify {Level} property exatcly in log message.

I was trying to use:

```
Matching.WithProperty<LogEventLevel>("Level", l => l == LogEventLevel.Warning)
```

but it didn't work too.

Comment: @Kiquenet, it's WCF application.

Comment: How do you log errors and log warnings in your code using Serilog ?

Comment: @Kiquenet, examples are below:

Error message with exception details: `Log.Logger.Error(ex, "Here goes error message with {Data}", someData)`
Warning message: `Log.Logger.Warning("Here goes warning message with {Data}", someData)`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49315287/serilog-and-filters-from-filters-expressions-in-appsettings-json

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you need:

```
.ByIncludingOnly(evt => evt.Level == LogEventLevel.Warning)
```

**Edit:**

In many cases it's now more succinct to use [*Serilog.Sinks.Map*](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map). With it, the example can be written as:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiuration()
    .WriteTo.Map(
        evt => evt.Level,
        (level, wt) => wt.RollingFile("Logs\\" + level + "-{Date}.log"))
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: ...mind looking at this question, the edit and last few comments in the answer...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47565008/trouble-converting-serilog-configuration-code-line-to-json-configuration/47566787?noredirect=1#comment82106820_47566787

Answer (score 55):

I use the following configuration and it works for me:

```
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                    .WriteTo.LiterateConsole()
                    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Information).WriteTo.RollingFile(@"Logs\Info-{Date}.log"))
                    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug      ).WriteTo.RollingFile(@"Logs\Debug-{Date}.log"))
                    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Warning    ).WriteTo.RollingFile(@"Logs\Warning-{Date}.log"))
                    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Error      ).WriteTo.RollingFile(@"Logs\Error-{Date}.log"))
                    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Fatal      ).WriteTo.RollingFile(@"Logs\Fatal-{Date}.log"))
                    .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"Logs\Verbose-{Date}.log")
                    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Upvoted not regarding to the question, but because of the clean solution presented for logging different log levels in separate files.

Comment: Like this one. The only question, is how it could be translated to JSON config file? I tried to find a syntax reference, but failed to to so for some reason.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this in json config. My VS plugin ignores the Filter line when generating json.

Answer (score 8):

Usually for my use-cases I need multiple logs that will contain a minimum level for each. This way I can later investigate the logs more efficiently.

For more recent versions of Serilog I would suggest to use this:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiuration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.File(path: "debug.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .WriteTo.File(path: "info.log", restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .WriteTo.File(path: "error.log",restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 3):

Serilog now has conditional sinks which make it really simple and clean to implement this:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.Conditional(
    evt => evt.Level == LogEventLevel.Debug,
    wt => wt.RollingFile(@"Logs\Debug-{Date}.log"))
.WriteTo.Conditional(
    evt => evt.Level == LogEventLevel.Warning,
    wt => wt.RollingFile(@"Logs\Warning-{Date}.log"))
.CreateLogger();
```

You can put whatever condition you like in the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind please, that **by default** minimum level is **Information** level, not Verbose/Debug.

**source** :
[image]

And this configuration **will not work** for Debug and Verbose levels :

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    //assumed that we are allow write to console for ALL cases [not!]
    .WriteTo.Conditional(evt => true, wt=>wt.Console())
    .CreateLogger();
```

And **it will work** in case you are defining base minimum allowed log level :

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Is(LogEventLevel.Debug) //or Verbose        
    .WriteTo.Conditional(evt => true, wt=>wt.Console())
    .CreateLogger();
```

[image]

Another one thing if you are using **Conditional**. To write some alternative to "minimum level" you can write something like this :

```
.WriteTo.Conditional(evt => evt.Level >= LogEventLevel.Debug, wt=>wt.Console())
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var dateTimeNowString = $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}";
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .WriteTo.Logger(
        x => x.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Error)
            .WriteTo.File($"Logs/{dateTimeNowString}-Error.log")
    )
    .WriteTo.Logger(
        x => x.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .WriteTo.File($"Logs/{dateTimeNowString}-Warning.log")
    )
    .WriteTo.File($"Logs/{dateTimeNowString}-All.log")
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateLogger();
```

These are my nuget packages:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant is to have ERROR and FATAL in one file (instead of errors in one file and fatal in another). Seems to many files for me having them separate. Just to keep in mind "or" operator can be used.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File("logs\\all.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .WriteTo.Logger(
        x => x.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(y => y.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Error || y.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Fatal)
        .WriteTo.File("logs\\error.log", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day))
    .CreateLogger();
```