# Serilog : Log to different files

Tags: c#, serilog

I am logging events of all types to single Json file irrespective of LogLevel. Now I have a requirement to log some custom performance counters to a seperate Json file. How can this be done in Serilog. Should I create different Logger Instance and use that where ever I am going to Log the performance counters? Want to use this with LibLog

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serilog - multiple log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292601/serilog-multiple-log-files)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do this by first making sure the performance counter events are tagged with either a particular property value (`OpenMappedContext()` in LibLog) or from a particular type/namespace.

```
var log = LogProvider.For<MyApp.Performance.SomeCounter>()
log.Info(...);
```

When configuring Serilog, a [sub-logger](http://nblumhardt.com/2016/07/serilog-2-write-to-logger/) with filter applied can send just the required events to the second file.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("MyApp.Performance"))
        .WriteTo.File("first.json", new JsonFormatter()))
    .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource("MyApp.Performance"))
        .WriteTo.File("second.json", new JsonFormatter()))
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: Read your write up : Serilog 2.0 adventures with sub-loggers. Not sure If I missed something, but, If I do this, the logs from ""MyApp.Performance" will go to outer logger as well right? I do not want these specific logs to be written to the main log file.

Comment: Adding two sub-logging pipelines with inverse filters should do it. Updating answer..

Comment: That worked for me. Edited answer to remove JsonFormatter.

Comment: Do you have json example of this?

Comment: I've tried to use `Log.ForContext("LogType", "blablabla")` and `WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Properties.ContainsKey("LogType") && e.Properties["LogType"].ToString() == "blablabla"), but it never worked: the corresponding file has been created, but nothing written there

Answer (score 14):

We can set it up in the configuration files too. Given below is a sample in the `appsettings.json` to split the log the rolling files based on levels

```
{
 
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "(@Level = 'Error' or @Level = 'Fatal' or @Level = 'Warning')"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "Logs/ex_.log",
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "(@Level = 'Information' or @Level = 'Debug')"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "Logs/cp_.log",
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:o} [{Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                  "rollingInterval": "Day",
                  "retainedFileCountLimit": 7
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithMachineName"
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "MultipleLogFilesSample"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you will only need to modify the `CreateHostBuilder` method in `Program.cs` file to read it from the configuration file

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfig) =>
                loggerConfig.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
            );
```

For more details, refer the post [here](https://www.techrepository.in/blog/posts/writing-logs-to-different-files-serilog-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have an independent logging pipeline, just make another instance.
This is robbed and adapted from https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Lifecycle-of-Loggers:

```
using (var performanceCounters = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.File(@"myapp\log.txt")
        .CreateLogger())
{
    performanceCounters.Information("Performance is really good today ;-)");

    // Your app runs, then disposal of `performanceCounters` flushes any buffers
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following code to log different levels to different files.

```
var conn = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:SqlConn").Value;

var serilogLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Information()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(conn, new MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = "ErrorLogs", AutoCreateSqlTable = true }, restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(conn, new MSSqlServerSinkOptions { TableName = "InfoLogs", AutoCreateSqlTable = true }, restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
            .CreateLogger();
```