# C# Serilog WriteTo based on condition at runtime inside a file

Tags: c#, serilog, fluentd

I know there is new update in serilog where you can do conditional logging as shown in below code however that is part of preconfiguration, ***but I need to write to either to File1 or File2 at run time***, well File1 will be used to push data to EventViewer and File2 will be used to push data to SQL database using fluentd.

```
bool enableFileLogging1 = ...
bool enableFileLogging2 = ...

var builder = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .MinimumLevel.Warning()
    .WriteTo.Conditional(evt => enableFileLogging1, wt => wt.File())
    .WriteTo.Conditional(evt => enableFileLogging2, wt => wt.File(...));

Log.Logger = builder.CreateLogger();
```

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38481227/serilog-log-to-different-files

Comment: Why not use configuration file https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan I have seen the post, not sure if I understood completely, there are filters based on file[ like controller/service] but I have a single file where both logs are logged how to apply filter inside a file, kind of subcategorizing.