# Add Multiple log file .netcore project by using serilog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, serilog

I added log file in my .netcore MVC project by using serilog and I read all parameter appsettings.json file. Serilog configuration is (in appsettings) like this.

In This solution, all logs are written in the one file. But I want to write different error message different files. Such as my X method errors are written xMethodLogs.txt and Y method errors are written yMethodLogs.txt

MyStartup.cs file is

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("default", "api/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}/{sad?}");
        });
    }


public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

My appsettings file is

```
"Serilog": { 
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" ], 
    "MinimumLevel": "Error", 
    "WriteTo": [ { 
        "Name": "RollingFile", 
        "Args": { "pathFormat": "C:\\MyPro\\ServiceLog.txt" } 
    } ], 
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ], 
    "Properties": { "Application": "Sample" } 
}
```

Comment: My appsettings file is  ` "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Error",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": { "pathFormat": "C:\\MyPro\\ServiceLog.txt" }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "Sample"
    }
  }`

Comment: You can take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292601/serilog-multiple-log-files `Filter.ByIncludingOnly`

Comment: I research this url but Filter.ByIncludingOnly is not working .netcore and I dont seperate logs error or warning. My logs are error in different methods or classes. I want to seperate different classess errors  or differents methods errors

Comment: I don't really know serilog but I did not find a way to create multiple loggers or something like that. Could you consider about changing the library ?

Comment: I dont know If I dont find any solition using serilog, I will change. Did you refer any library in this solition?

Comment: You can achieve what you want with NLog https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki

Comment: See this answer for the solution...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292601/serilog-multiple-log-files?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thaks @dinotom I solve this problem using NLog but I will note this solution ((: