# Trouble converting Serilog Configuration code line to json configuration

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-core, serilog

I found a post where the blogger explained how to filter by LogEvent level to a separate file for Serilog configuration. I am doing all my Serilog configuration in my appsettings.json. How would this look in json configuration, I can't seem to figure how to json the lambda expression....

```
Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Warning).WriteTo.RollingFile(@"Logs\Warning-{Date}.log"))
```

I am using configuration for Serilog from my appsettings.json and am trying to convert this

```
.WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Warning).WriteTo.RollingFile(@"Logs\ApplicationName\Serilog\Warning-{Date}.log"))
```

to json, to include in my Serilog section of my appsettings file

**EDIT:**
appsettings partial shown here

```
 "WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Console",
    "Args": {
      "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] ({SourceContext}) {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Seq",
    "Args": { "serverUrl": "http://localhost:5341" }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Async",
    "Args": {
      "configure": [
        {
          "Name": "RollingFile",
          "Args": { "pathFormat": "C:/Logs/Serilog/%APPLICATION_NAME%/log-{Date}.log" }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
],
"SubLogger": {
  "Level": "Warnings",
  "pathFormat": "C:/Logs/Serilog/%APPLICATION_NAME%/Warnings/log-{Date}.log"
},
```

The sub logger pathFormat is not producing the same folder naming as the RollingFile pathFormat

[image: File Explorer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this moment Serilog does not support configuration of sub-loggers through JSON appsettings. See this [issue](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/issues/37) on github.

It's not an easy task actually because you pass `Func<LogEvent, bool>` to `ByIncludingOnly()` filter. Mapping configuration data from json file to c# code is not a trivial task.

However if you are just interested in creation of sub-logger for specific log level, you could combine configuration from JSON config with `ByIncludingOnly()` filter.

Define a POCO that will hold filter configuration:

```
public class SubLoggerConfiguration
{
    public LogEventLevel Level { get; set; }

    private string pathFormat;
    public string PathFormat
    {
        get => pathFormat;
        set => pathFormat = value.Replace("%APPLICATION_NAME%", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPLICATION_NAME"));
    }
}
```

Add `SubLogger` section to your JSON config:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": { "pathFormat": "c:\\Logs\\log-{Date}.log" }
      }
    ],

    "SubLogger": {
      "Level": "Warning",
      "pathFormat": "Logs\\ApplicationName\\Serilog\\Warning-{Date}.log"
    } 
  }
}
```

It's a good idea to keep it inside native Serilog section, it will not break configuration of Serilog itself.

Then load `SubLogger` configuration from config file:

```
IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile("AppSettings.json");
IConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
SubLoggerConfiguration subLoggerConfiguration = new SubLoggerConfiguration();
configuration.GetSection("Serilog:SubLogger").Bind(subLoggerConfiguration);
```

Note that you have to install `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` NuGet package for binding configuration to a POCO.

Now subLoggerConfiguration will contain desired log level and path format for the log. You can use this settings to call `ByIncludingOnly()` filter:

```
Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == subLoggerConfiguration.Level).WriteTo.RollingFile(subLoggerConfiguration.PathFormat));
```

Comment: @CodeFuller...one issue...in my main serilog config {
              "Name": "RollingFile",
              "Args": { "pathFormat": "C:/Logs/Serilog/%APPLICATION_NAME%/log-{Date}.log" }
            }  creates the proper file folder using the name from my environment variable but in your sublogger section, the same path format construction..."SubLogger": {
      "Level": "Warnings",
      "pathFormat": "C:/Logs/Serilog/%APPLICATION_NAME%/Warnings/log-{Date}.log"
    }   produces the file path...Logs/Serilog/%APPLICATION_NAME%/Warnings

Comment: Any reason in the sublogger section it is not picking up the %APPLICATION_NAME% variable?

Comment: Serilog has a logic for substitution of %APPLICATION_NAME% pattern with corresponding environment variable. Actually any other variable will work too. You could do the same, see updated `SubLoggerConfiguration` in my answer (it's a sample for APPLICATION_NAME only).

Comment: "Serilog has a logic for substitution of %APPLICATION_NAME% pattern with corresponding environment variable."...I know that, that is why I am using it in my RollingFile configuration (where it IS working), but that same path is not applying the variable name to the path in the Sublogger section...is there a reason it has to be defined in the class?

Comment: @CodeFuller...See my post edit for details. And thank you again for all your answers to Serilog ?'s

Comment: Have you tried updated `SubLoggerConfiguration` from my answer with substitution of `%APPLICATION_NAME%`?

Comment: @CodeFuller...not yet, I know that will work. I am trying to figure out WHY it doesn't work the way I have it, it should.

Comment: It will not work without special code for substitution of such pattern with actual value of environment variable. Serilog configuration loader has such code. `RollingFile()` extension method that you use for configuring file logging does not have such substitution. That's why you should do it by yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160217/discussion-between-dinotom-and-codefuller).