# Serilog and Filters from Filters.Expressions in appsettings.json

Tags: logging, .net-core, console-application, serilog

We would like to get log for:

1. Console (all log)
2. File (all log)
3. File (**only filtered log**)

All of this configured in appsettings.json.

This is the appsettings.json file for the application:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Literate", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Filters.Expressions" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Verbose",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "LiterateConsole"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "%TEMP%\\Logs\\FileWithoutFilter-.log",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "%TEMP%\\Logs\\UPLOADERROR-.log",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        },
        "Filter": [
          {
            "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
            "Args": {
              "expression": "@Level = 'Error' and UploadError is not null"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But, in spite of Console and File (without filtering) is running fine, File with filtering is logging all the lines, like the file (without filter).

We are sending this log.error line in C# code:

```
Log.Error("Fichero con error {@UploadError}", true);
```

But, I have said, all lines are logged to UPLOADERROR file

Some idea what is wrong in the appsettings.file?

Regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is using subloggers with serilog. You must then configure the sublogger with the filtering and the sink.

Careful reading of serilog documentation related to general, configuration and filters, was the trick.

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Literate", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Filters.Expressions" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Verbose",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "LiterateConsole"
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "%TEMP%\\Logs\\FileWithoutFilter-.log",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "rollingInterval": "Day"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "@Level = 'Error' and UploadError is not null"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "%TEMP%\\Logs\\UPLOADERROR-.log",
                  "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With previous configuration all is working fine now.

Comment: Can you show how your serilog registration on Program.cs with this same configuration. I am trying to implement the same thing but one of the logs is always missing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have access to this project anymore.  I don't think the problem is with serilog dependency registration, anyway.  Regards.

Comment: Serilog.Filters.Expressions were not installed due to that the filter expression was not working properly. I installed that and now it is working.

Comment: as described by @Rasik, the missing package was a problem for us too. But be aware: Serilog.Filters.Expressions now is deprecated. Please use Serilog.Expressions instead

Comment: in the new package (serilog.expressions) the syntax has changed and  `@Level `is now `@l`