# Configure Serilog to filter certain logs to a different file using appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

I have an application which uses Serilog to write log-data to a file. I'm now trying to configure my logger with sub-loggers in `appsettings.json` in such a way so that I can filter certain logs to a different file. I'm aware that I could configure the logger in code, but I want to do it via `appsettings.json`.

Basically, I want all logs to go to the same file, except a certain type of log. I used the  [Serilog wiki](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki) and a few blog posts and stackoverflow entries, mainly [this one](https://bnolan.org/2021/08/10/using-serilog-sub-loggers-in-net-core-5/), to achieve my goal.From what I've read using the following should allow me to filter for this type of log entry:

```
using (LogContext.PushProperty("SpecialLogType", true)) {
    _logger.LogInformation("MyLogEntry {MyParam}", myParam);
}
```

I configured two sinks, one for normal logs and one for this special type of log. Using filters, I should now be able to filter logs using this property. But I can't figure out how exactly I need to configure the subloggers in appsettings.json.
Right now, my `appsettings.json` looks like this:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Settings.Configuration", "Serilog.Expressions" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByExcluding",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "@p['SpecialLogType'] = 'true'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "Logs/NormalTypeLog_.txt",
                  // other configuration
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "@p['SpecialLogType'] = 'true'"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "Logs/SpecialTypeLog.json",
                  // other configuration
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I've tried several different things with some results but I can't get it to work properly and would appreachiate some advice. Does anyone have any tipps?

Edit: Found this question much later which also provides an alternative answer: [Serilog and Filters from Filters.Expressions in appsettings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49315287/serilog-and-filters-from-filters-expressions-in-appsettings-json)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I managed to figure this out a few days later and figured I'd post my complete solution here if anyone with a similar issue stumbles upon it.

I think I was on the right path but my main issue was my incorrect use of of [Serilog's expressions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions) package. I had mixed things I've found in multiple examples together, which didn't end up working. More reading in wikis and [nblumhardt's blog posts](https://nblumhardt.com/2021/03/serilog-expressions-2/) guided me to my eventual solution.

### Filtering log events to different files via Serilog's appsettings.json configuration

Logs can be enriched with properties. These properties can be used later in the pipeline to filter logs to different [subloggers](https://nblumhardt.com/2016/07/serilog-2-write-to-logger/). Properties can be added to logs via the `LogContext` class.

```
using (LogContext.PushProperty("SpecialLogType", true)) {
    _logger.LogInformation("This is a log entry that will be filtered to a different file");
}
```

To actually configure the loggers, you need to create two sub-loggers. **The filtering has to happen at the sub-logger level**. Each sublogger has to filter it's own events. Filtering at the top-level logger will filter out log events for all it's subloggers. Filtering is done via [Serilog's expressions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions) package.

To only include log event's with my property attached, I did the following

```
"Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
"Args": {
  "expression": "SpecialLogType is not null"
}
```

Since I wanted all other events to go to the "standard" file, for my other sublogger I just excluded all log events with the property attached

```
"Name": "ByExcluding",
"Args": {
  "expression": "SpecialLogType is not null"
}
```

Full relevant appsettings.json section

```
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Settings.Configuration", "Serilog.Expressions" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      { "Name": "Debug" },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByExcluding",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "SpecialLogType is not null"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "Logs/NormalLogEvents_.txt",
                  // other irrelevant file configuration
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "SpecialLogType is not null"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "File",
                "Args": {
                  "path": "Logs/SpecialLoggingType_.log",
                  // other irrelevant file configuration
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
  }
```

This worked for me and I hope it helps anyone having the same issue.

Also useful: [Serilog settings configuration readme](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is you have to use below expression in filter if you are using Serilog.Expressions instead of Serilog.Filters.Expressions

```
Serilog.Filters.Expressions : 
"Filter": 
 [ 
   {
         "Name": "ByIncludingOnly", "Args": { "expression": "@Level = 'Error'" } 
   } 
 ]


Serilog.Expressions :
 "Filter": 
[ 
  { 
     "Name": "ByIncludingOnly", "Args": { "expression": "@l = 'Error'" }
  } 
]
```

Its working fine for me

Comment: This filters only by level, what if you're working in a big project where all levels are already in use but you still want to only filter certain events regardless of level?