# Serilog different log file per level

Tags: logging, .net-core, serilog

I want my logs to persist in different folders based on their level. And I want this configuration to be completely via config file rather than [hard-coded configs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292601/serilog-multiple-log-files) as it may change in future. Doing so in `NLog` [configuration file](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/File-target#per-level-log-files) is pretty easy, but I didn't find it how to do advanced log configuration in `Serilog`. Any suggestion?

Currently I have this:

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "logs\\AppLogs_.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Hour",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 15000000,
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "shared": true,
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level}]) {Message} {NewLine} {Exception}"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ]


  }
```

Comment: You can override it on a per sink level according to the [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#overriding-per-sink)

Comment: @SimplyGed, that's a code change, as I said, I want to config it per level in conifguration, I didn't find a sample config file for per level config

Comment: Have you tried adding `"restrictedLevelMinimum": "Debug"` to the config `Args`?

Comment: Also, as that document says, you can't change the config level on a per-sink basis: From the docs `the logger-level configuration controls which logging statements will result in the creation of events, while the sink-level configuration only filters these. To create a single logger with a more verbose level, use a separate LoggerConfiguration.`

Comment: `restrictedLevelMinimum` didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old post but for anyone having this problem here is my solution.

You need to create a config file for each level you want separated. I have:

```
Serilog.Debug.json
Serilog.Information.json
Serilog.Error.json
Serilog.Warning.json
```

In these 4 files you need to have the following confinguration:

```
{
  "Serilog:WriteTo:3:Args:configureLogger": { //notice this key
     "WriteTo": [
     {
         "Name": "File",
         "Args": {
         "path": "some path containing the log level"
          }
     }
     ],
"Filter": [
  {
    "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
    "Args": {
      "expression": "@l = 'Debug'"
     }
   }
   ]
}
}
```

Then you can have another file for Fatal `Serilog.json` and the following content:

```
{
"Serilog": {
"Enrich": [
  "FromLogContext",
  "WithMachineName"
],
"restrictedToMinimumLevel": null,
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "Logs/Fatal_.txt",
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Fatal"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Logger",
    "Args": {
      "configureLogger": {} // leave this empty: Information
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Logger",
    "Args": {
      "configureLogger": {} // leave this empty: Warning
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Logger",
    "Args": {
      "configureLogger": {} // leave this empty: Debug
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Logger",
    "Args": {
      "configureLogger": {} // leave this empty: Error
    }
  }
]
}
}
```

In order for all these to work you need at least the following packages:

```
Serilog.Sinks.File
Serilog.Expressions
Serilog.Expressions.Logging
```