# how make separated log via serilog?

Tags: c#, serilog

"A" project use "B" library that i make.
and i want use make log for "B" library's and "A" project both but i want they each seprated.
some similar question in here i saw that
[Serilog - multiple log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292601/serilog-multiple-log-files)
here and
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile/issues/72
here and so on.
but these answer's explain that separate log via event level based.
am i right? or Something missunderstanded?

Comment: just use separate `ILogger`.

Comment: @DanielA.White can i ask some examples? Or do you know related documentation?